# task superDev gives an error. Below is the result of stacktrace

Tags: libgdx

---

```
13:41:12: Executing 'superDev --scan --stacktrace'...

> Task :core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:createInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :html:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:prepareInplaceWebApp UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:addSource

> Task :html:draftCompileGwt
C:\Programming files\Projects\JavaProjects\LibgdxProjects\html\.
../assets
Copying resources from ../assets to war/
C:\Programming files\Projects\JavaProjects\LibgdxProjects\html\..\assets
C:\Programming files\Projects\JavaProjects\LibgdxProjects\html\assets
C:\Programming files\Projects\JavaProjects\LibgdxProjects\html\.
../assets
Copying resources from ../assets to war/
C:\Programming files\Projects\JavaProjects\LibgdxProjects\html\..\assets
C:\Programming files\Projects\JavaProjects\LibgdxProjects\html\assets
Compiling module com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinitionSuperdev
   [ERROR] Errors in 'generated://EDE6402AFBDE09D1E8D4A9C9E9098379/com/badlogic/gwtref/client/IReflectionCache2Generated.java'
      [WARN] Line 15151: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.ancestorsVisible': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.ancestorsVisible()' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 15952: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActor': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActor(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 15953: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActorAt': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActorAt(ILcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 15954: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActorBefore': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActorBefore(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 15955: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActorAfter': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Container.addActorAfter(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16343: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.setWidget': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.setWidget(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16344: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.getWidget': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.getWidget()' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16345: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActor': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActor(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16346: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActorAt': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActorAt(ILcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16347: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActorBefore': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActorBefore(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16348: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActorAfter': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane.addActorAfter(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor;)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16453: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.showList': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.showList()' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16455: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.hideList': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.hideList()' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16526: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider.setSnapToValues': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider.setSnapToValues([FF)' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 16920: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree.getNodes': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree.getNodes()' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 17323: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Selection.hasItems': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Selection.hasItems()' is deprecated
      [WARN] Line 17673: Referencing method 'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonValue.size': method 'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonValue.size()' is deprecated
      [ERROR] Line 7088: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsMethod; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 7328: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsIgnore; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 7342: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsType; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 7595: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsProperty; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCache2Generated'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'generated://EDE6402AFBDE09D1E8D4A9C9E9098379/com/badlogic/gwtref/client/IReflectionCache2Generated.java'
         [ERROR] Line 7088: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsMethod; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 7595: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsProperty; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 7342: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsType; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 7328: No source code is available for type jsinterop.annotations.JsIgnore; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCache2Generated' is really what you meant
   [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots
   [ERROR] Errors in 'com/badlogic/gwtref/client/ReflectionCache.java'
      [ERROR] Line 23: Rebind result 'com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCache2Generated' could not be found

> Task :html:draftCompileGwt FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':html:draftCompileGwt'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\twinrael\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':html:draftCompileGwt'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\twinrael\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:431)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:52)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.javaexec(DefaultExecActionFactory.java:195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1224)
    at org.docstr.gradle.plugins.gwt.AbstractGwtActionTask.exec(AbstractGwtActionTask.java:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:108)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at 
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)


BUILD FAILED in 11s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
6 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 4 up-to-date

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no]
```

I use:
jdk-21, gradle 8.5, when creating the project, I chose only html in libgdx-setup and Box2d.
There are no problems when I select desktop and Box2d when creating a project in gdx-setup.

I tried changing the jdk version, but it didn't help
I didn't find what I needed in Google and the gpt chat didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure Java 11 or Java 17 doesn't work? You could try generating a project using [gdx-liftoff](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-liftoff) instead, which should have more a up-to-date version of GWT.

Comment: You were right that the problem is in the gwt version